# How long would cutting phase last

Tags: cutting, bulking

I've been working out for about two years and I am planning to go on my second cut next year. I'm currently on a bulk weighing 154 pounds standing 5"10.(11%BFP currently) (137pounds, 7%BFP on my last cut) I'm planning to bulk up to 165 pounds making use of my remaining 3months of bulking. I'm planning to cut down to 143-145pounds (85BFP). While planning I would be grateful on tips to plan cutting, and I want to hear out how long you guys plan your cut. I'm currently planning from about 2-3 months. Let me know what you think. Thanks!!

Comment: At your weight I think you're looking for ~1lb a week loss, max. So quick math says 20 weeks.